# Save every 2 lines into a file

Tags: bash, unix, bioinformatics

I try to read a file and create a new file for every 2 lines. The new files should be saved in a different directory. The first line should be the file name and the second line should be the string within the file.

Input file looks like that:

```
>sample1
abcdefg
>sample2
xyz
>sample_n...
string_n...
```

I have tried to use the following awk command

```
awk -v FS=">" '$1 { file = $2 } { print $0 > /new_folder/new_file }' input_file
```

But it doesn't work.
Any suggestion ?

Comment: Why did you set the field separator to TAB character?

Comment: `saved in a different directory` - if the first line is the directory and the second line is the file content... how should the each different directory be named?  Please post output file structure including file content that should be the result of parsing the sample input file. Should it be file `./????/sample1` with content `abcdefg`, file `./whats here/sample2` with content `xyz`, file `./i dont know/sample_n...` with content `string_n...`?

Comment: What's the expected output?  a single file containing the odd lines from an input file?

Comment: Can you clarify the input format - original posting indicates TSV, but edit indicates no space between '>' and file name. I can revise my answer, but it will help if you can confirm input format, and post sample output

Comment: i have edited the file so there will be no space between the '>' and file name.

Comment: Are those 'fasta' files ? Can you advise the the answer address the problem ?

Comment: yes it is a fasta file. every header '>' is a genotype name and the line underneath it is a gene seq in the in that genotype

Answer (score 1):

The OP does not include sample output, but from the `awk` attempted solution looks like the following

- Input line the start with '>' specify the file name
- Other lines should be written to the last specified name
- All files should placed into separate folder
- The '>...' line is NOT placed into the output files

Modified solution to fix syntax and logic below, keeping same structure. The dir input parameter name the target folder for files to be created ('new_folder' in the example).

The 'new_folder' should be replaced with the actual name of the target folder (/path/to/folder, or similar).

```
awk -v 'FS=\t' -v "dir=new_folder" '
$1 = /^>/ { if (new_file ) close (new_file) ; new_file = dir "/" substr($1, 2) ; next }
{ print $0 > new_file }
'
```